# Passing null into a SQL command

Tags: c#, sql

I have a class:

```
public class Intlist
{
    public int yesFlag{ get; set; }
    public int? noFlag { get; set; }
}
```

I need to update a database table, but sometimes the value is null for the nullable ints. I am using

```
CommandText = @"UPDATE thetable 
                SET Yes = " + list.yesFlag +
                   ",NoFlag = " + (list.previous == null) ? DBNull.Value : list.previous +
                   ",NextValue = 10"
```

I'm trying to get it so that if noFlag is null, it enters a null in the database, but I'm getting errors:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

and

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'string'

Comment: Dont you use parameters?

Comment: It's not possible to pass a DBNull into SQL with the command you are using. Try using "NULL" as the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sayka** was on target. **Use parameters**.

Not only will you protect your database from sql injection attacks but you can take advantage of .Nets built in functionality to handle these types of issues.

```
    CommandText = @"UPDATE thetable SET Yes = @yesFlag, NoFlag = @noflag, NextValue = 10";
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yesFlag", list.yesFlag);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noFlag", list.previous);
```

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest solution.

Comment: I changed it to this but now i get 'expects the parameter '@noFlag', which was not supplied.' because its null

Comment: try creating the parameter then passing in either the value or DBNull.Value if the value is null. Then add the Parameter to the parameter collection.    -->   "SqlParameter noFlag = new SqlParameter("@noFlag", SqlDbType.Int);
        noFlag.Value = (object)list.previous ?? DBNull.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(noFlag);"

Answer (score 1):

Using parameters is strongly recommended. But in your case you just enter as 'Null'. It will work.

```
CommandText = @"UPDATE thetable SET Yes = " + 
             list.yesFlag.ToString() + ",NoFlag = " + (list.previous == null 
             ? "NULL" : list.previous) + ",NextValue = 10";
```

This query will go as it is.

Comment: @cubrr is correct. This will not compile. Do `(list.previous == null ? "NULL" : list.previous)` instead.

Comment: i get a "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'int?' " error

Comment: You have declared yes flag as int in that class, so you might need to use .ToString(). See my updated answer